# Efficient way to drop rows based on custom function

Tags: python, pandas

I am processing a Pandas dataframe and I want to filter out the rows that don't meet a specific condition. The dataframe has a `content` column that contains examples of Javascript code. The goal is to parse each snippet, remove its comments and only keep it if its length is above a certain threshold (e.g. above 200 characters after parsing).

I have the following code:

```
def computeSnippetLength(self, row):
    try:
        snippet = row['content']
        (... parsing code ...)
        snippetLength = len(parsedSnippet)
    except Exception as error:
        if self.debug:
            print(error)
            print(row['filename'])
        return False
    return True if snippetLength > 200 else False
```

So now I want to remove the rows whose content doesn't meet the 200 characters minimum. I have a relatively simple solution using `apply`:

```
def removeSmallFiles(self):
    self.df = self.df[self.df.apply(lambda row: self.computeSnippetLength(row), axis=1) == True]
```

However, I was looking for a more elegant and efficient solution, ideally without using `apply` which pretty much creates a new Series and removes the rows based on its values. Is there a simpler way using, `drop` for example? I couldn´t come up with a more efficient solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your function is accessing 2 columns by their names, applying `df.apply` seems to be an explicit and straightforward way. 
`df.drop[df.index[~<your_function_results>]]` won't perform faster.
Not readable, but a bit faster way (in your case) is traversing over `df.iterrows()`:

```
self.df = self.df[[self.computeSnippetLength(r) for _, r in self.df.iterrows()]]
```

---

I'd go with `df.apply` with eliminating redundant boolean checks (you don't need them) as follows:

```
def computeSnippetLength(self, row):
    ...
    return snippetLength > 200


def removeSmallFiles(self):
    self.df = self.df[self.df.apply(self.computeSnippetLength, axis=1)]
```

---

If you decide to not log/debug another columns, simplify your function to accept just a singular value from `self.df['content']` column:

```
def computeSnippetLength(self, content):
    try:
        (... parsing content code ...)
        snippetLength = len(parsedSnippet)
    except Exception as error:
        if self.debug:
            print(error)
        return False
    return snippetLength > 200
```

Then, filter df by:

```
self.df = self.df[[self.computeSnippetLength(v) for v in self.df['content']]]
```

This should run the fastest among the above approaches.

Comment: I don't actually need to access both, one of them is solely for logging reasons. I'm guessing that wouldn't change much though, would it? code wise.

Comment: @GRoutar, the code you've posted relies on potential logging another column. The one should not guess weather the parsing throw an error or not (to debug/log the broken file), right?

Comment: Yeah its just to log which files failed to parse. Only for debugging purposes though. The final solution doesn't require to print row['filename']

Comment: @GRoutar, see my update

Comment: Thanks. I don't particularly like the fact that iterating the Series is faster than Pandas' built-ins.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but I will accept it as the answer. Thank you!